# CPU usage drops on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, tensorflow, multiprocessing

[image]

I was using AWS c5.4xlarge instance, which has 16 vCPU, and running a 10 processes python programme. However, the CPU usage of each process gradually dropped down to 10% as showed in the picture in just 10 seconds. The total CPU usage of the 16 vCPU instances was just about 6%.

I reduced the number of the processes, but the CPU usage of each process was still quite low. Everything is ok on my own macOS.

[image]

What is wrong with this?

Comment: what do you mean that everything was OK on your Mac? Were the CPU cores more occupied? Was the result of the computation on AWS correct? Did it come (much) faster than on your Mac?

Comment: The c5.4xlarge doesn't seem to have a GPU.  Outside my expertise, but possibly useful: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/255

Comment: Yes, I mean that if I run this programme with 3 child processes on my mac, each process will take about 130% CPU usage and thus the 4-core CPU of my mac is almost used up. But when I run the same programme with 3 child processes on the aws instance, each process only takes about 30 - 40 % CPU usage, although there are 1600% vCPU in total. The result of AWS actually is correct. I haven't compare the speed yet because it take much time to finish the whole programme. @diginoise

Comment: There is no GPU on my mac as well and I do not intend to use one. But that may cause the problem.. By the way, it seems like the precesses tended to be run on a single cpu. Each of the 10 precesses took about 10% CPU usage and 100% in total. And when the number of processes was 3, each of them took about 30% - 40%. Weird..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the answer. This is about processor affinity. For Linux beginner:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity

In Linux you can allocate a cpu to a specific process in the Linux ternimal:

```
$ taskset -cp CPU_ID PID
```

For example:

```
$ taskset -cp 0-1 1000
```

will allocate CPU 0 and 1 to process with ID 1000.

You can find the PID by using

```
$ top
```

in your terminal.